# Returning one row from foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have this model:

```
public function get_products_by_slug($slug)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result(); 
    }
```

And this controller:

```
public function products($category)
    {

        $data['products_by_category'] = $this->products_model->get_products_by_slug($category);

        if (empty($data['products_by_category']))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['main_content'] = 'pages/products_by_category';
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
    }
```

And in the view for the title of the page as a banner in the page I want to use both those function to grab just the first category field in the database to use it as the title. I know that there is way in the model that I can grab just the first row. But what I want is not make another model just for that I want to use those functions above to use it for the title and the rest of the page to show the all products.

the view page:

```
<?php foreach($products_by_category as $row){
    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo '<h1>'.$row->category(1).'</h1>';
    echo '<hr/>';
    echo '</div>'; } ?>
```

now this way above it will make as much  with the same name of the category as there is in the database. what I want is only one name for the title.

Comment: So where it the "title" value derived from? Also, are you basically saying that you want to output column headers before the foreach loop?

Comment: I want to grab the slug field as category name to put it in the banner of the page and for the title of the page in the header. where I put is not that importan what is important is how to grab one row from the foreach loop

Comment: What about  `return $query->row_array();`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I'm trying to use these functions for two purposes on to grab one row for the title of the page and the other one to show all the products in the database in the page. that's why return `$query->row_array();` won't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching around the web the answer was so simple. You don't need the foreach loop just use the passed variable with the number of the row in the array and the name of the field. just like that.

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="container">';
        echo '<h1>'.$products_by_category[1]['category'].'</h1>';
        echo '<hr/>';
    echo '</div>'; 
  ?>
```